# Put every line of a string into separate variables in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a multi-line string in PHP like this:

```
"Line1 - message1
 Line2 - message2"
```

Now I want to put each line into a separate variable (no array)
So when I call `echo $var1` it returns `Line 1 - message1` and the same thing for each line.
How to do this in PHP?

Comment: You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with `\n` to get 2 lines in an array

Comment: You may use regular expressions. I do not know how that would in `php` but in perl: `@list_of_strings =  split "\n", $multiline_string;` or use regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $multipleLines);
echo $lines[0];
```

`explode` will split your string of multiple lines at each new line character `\n` and put each line into an element of the array.

Comment: It justs unifies them. It doesn't split them. $lines[0] returns the whole string with no line breaks and $lines[1] returns nothing

Comment: can you help me??

Comment: Works for me.  Go to http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/cvmr-48e3 and click "Run - F9".

Comment: Was my problem. Solved it anyway